# How to profile a stress test for a distributed system in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, I have looked into other threads but could not find a single tool (all in one) for profiling performance.
I want to profile system performance while doing some stress testing. 
The system is written into many .py files and have many processes running at the same time. Mainly interested in CPU, Memory, Time and Throughput.

Comment: You could try to combine Locust (https://locust.io) and Zabbix (https://www.zabbix.com). Both are free and incredibly easy to use, and while Locust can do the stress test, Zabbix can deeply monitor your CPU.